# Pass stim flags to sinter

Tags: stim

While using stim (in python) to build detector error models it is possible to pass flags such as `ignore_decomposition_failures=True` etc.

How can I pass such flags to sinter for automated samplng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this from the command line, but it can be done with the python API.

When you create a `sinter.Task`, one of the arguments you can specify is the `detector_error_model`. Normally this is set to `None`, which means "automatically figure it out from the circuit". In cases where this fails you can instead manually make a detector error model and pass that:

```
custom_dem = circuit.detector_error_model(
    decompose_errors=True,
    ignore_decomposition_failures=True,
)

task = sinter.Task(
    circuit=circuit,
    detector_error_model=custom_dem,
    ...
)
```

Beware that pymatching is liable to get upset if you pass it a detector error model with undecomposed errors.

Comment: Pymatching did indeed complain about the undecomposed errors. I can still do what I need with TableauSimulator and manual editing of the dem. Thanks for the quick reply though!

Comment: @wordy If you really want to go hard on "ignore this problem", you can actually remove the undecomposed error instructions from the DEM (by iterating over it appending instructions to a new empty DEM except for the bad ones).